# jquery - Hiding/showing fieldset not consistent

Tags: jquery

my jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/justmelat/QnKeZ/

I hide fieldsets on load of page, then display a particular fieldset based on the product type selected from the dropdown.  I thought I had this working, but after you select from the product type dropdown a few times, the sections that should hide or not hiding.

How should I could this or what am I missing?

**my jsfiddle is here:** `http://jsfiddle.net/justmelat/QnKeZ/`

**HTML here >>**

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <div id="holdMsg"></div>
    <fieldset id="mainSection" name="mainSection">
                <legend style="color:blue; font-weight:bold">Project Overview Section</legend>

                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 33px; width: 178px;">Name</td>
                        <td style="height: 33px"><input  id="1125" name="1125" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 33px; width: 178px;">Email</td>
                        <td style="height: 33px"><input  id="1026" name="1026" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 178px">Product Title</td>
                        <td><input  id="1089" name="1089" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 178px">Product Type</td>
                        <td><select id="1169" name="1169">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                        <option value="Cars">Cars</option>
                        <option value="Boats">Boats</option>
                        <option value="Planes">Planes</option>
                        </select></td>
                    </tr>
                                    </table>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset id="section-11" name="section-11">
                <legend style="color:fuchsia; font-weight:bold">Car Details Section</legend>

                <table cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px; height: 35px"><label>Size:</label></td>
                        <td style="height: 35px"><input id="1245" name="1245" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 35px; width: 334px">Color:</td>
                        <td style="height: 35px">
                        <select id="1433" name="1433">
                <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
                        <option value="Blank">Blank</option>
                        <option value="Green">Green</option>
            </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px">Description:</td>
                        <td>
                        <textarea id="1290" name="1290" rows="2" style="width: 433px"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                            </fieldset>

            <fieldset id="section-12" name="section-12">
                <legend style="color:fuchsia; font-weight:bold">Plane Details Section</legend>

                <table cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px; height: 35px"><label>Size:</label></td>
                        <td style="height: 35px"><input id="1245" name="1245" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 35px; width: 334px">Color:</td>
                        <td style="height: 35px">
                        <select id="1433" name="1433">
                <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
                        <option value="Blank">Blank</option>
                        <option value="Green">Green</option>
            </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px">Description:</td>
                        <td>
                        <textarea id="1290" name="1290" rows="2" style="width: 433px"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="section-13" name="section-13">
                <legend style="color:fuchsia; font-weight:bold">Boat Details Section</legend>

                <table cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px; height: 35px"><label>Size:</label></td>
                        <td style="height: 35px"><input id="1245" name="1245" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 35px; width: 334px">Color:</td>
                        <td style="height: 35px">
                        <select id="1433" name="1433">
                <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
                        <option value="Blank">Blank</option>
                        <option value="Green">Green</option>
            </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px">Description:</td>
                        <td>
                        <textarea id="1290" name="1290" rows="2" style="width: 433px"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                            </fieldset><br>
<fieldset id="section-1011" name="section-1011">
                <legend style="color:green; font-weight:bold">Misc Info Section</legend>

                <table cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px; height: 35px"><label>Size:</label></td>
                        <td style="height: 35px"><input id="1301" name="1301" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 35px; width: 334px">Color:</td>
                        <td style="height: 35px">
                        <select id="1302" name="1302">
                <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
                        <option value="Blank">Blank</option>
                        <option value="Green">Green</option>
            </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px">Description:</td>
                        <td>
                        <textarea id="1303" name="1303" rows="2" style="width: 433px"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                            </fieldset>


</form>
```

**jquery here >>**

```
$("#section-11").hide();
$("#section-12").hide();
$("#section-13").hide();
$("#section-1011").hide();

var projtype = new Array(
        {value : 'Cars', sect_id : 'fieldset#section-11'},
        {value : 'Planes', sect_id : 'fieldset#section-12'},
        {value : 'Boats', sect_id : 'fieldset#section-13'}
    );
$("select#1169").on('change',function () {
var thisVal = $(this).val();
 var sect_id ="";
    $(projtype).each(function() {
$(this.sect_id).hide();
        if(this.value == thisVal) {
        $(this.sect_id).show();
        return false;
        }
    });        
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `return false;` from your `each` function.

This `return` statement stops executing your `each` iteration and stops hiding other fieldsets.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#section-11").hide();
$("#section-12").hide();
$("#section-13").hide();
$("#section-1011").hide();

var projtype = new Array({
    value: 'Cars',
    sect_id: 'fieldset#section-11'
}, {
    value: 'Planes',
    sect_id: 'fieldset#section-12'
}, {
    value: 'Boats',
    sect_id: 'fieldset#section-13'
});
$("select#1169").on('change', function() {
    var thisVal = $(this).val();
    $('fieldset[id!="mainSection"]').hide();
    var sect_id = "";
    $(projtype).each(function() {
        if (this.value == thisVal) {
            $(this.sect_id).show();
        }
    });
});
```

See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tkB7S/2/)

Comment: wow that works - do you know why mine did not work.  I am just learning jquery and do real programming with it at the same time [not good I know], I am thinking "down the road", it would be safer to just say hide the FS's that have not been selected in the array.  I see the potential for a client to have 2, 3 5 FS that they may want to "always" display, so I don't want to list each.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `return false;`. Is there, any, specific reason for keeping it in there?
Your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QnKeZ/8/).

Comment: That's it.  I copied that from another bit of code I was using and didn't remove it.  THANK YOU!!!!